# ASP MVC 5 - keep @html.checkbox state after page reload after clicking "submit button"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I created a page that I can search the store detail via entity framework
I added a column of checkbox in the table. 
I would like to keep the checkbox "checked=True" after I submit via the search button.

What would be the recommend way to achieve that ?

I tried following method, but the checkbox get "unchecked" after I click submit
1. https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

View as following :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
    <input type="submit"  name ="StoreIndexButton" value="Search" />
</p>
}
<table class="table" id="displayresult">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.market)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.oper)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.operator)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.store1 })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBox("selected",new { value = item.store1,     id="selected"+item.store1.ToString() })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Controller as following :

```
public ActionResult Index(string StoreIndexButton,string searchString)
{
    var AR_stores = (from m in db.stores
                     select m).Take(10);
    string[] selectedList = Request.Form.GetValues("selected");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && StoreIndexButton =="Search")
    {
         AR_stores = (from m in db.stores
                      select m).Where(s =>   s.name.Contains(searchString));
    }
    return View(AR_stores);    
}
```

Model as following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class store
{
    public int store1 { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string market { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string oper { get; set; }
    public string operator { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would on this way :

on partial class add a flag parameter.

```
public string checkStatus {get; set;}
```

on default, this will be false and none of choices will be selected.

After submit the function, you have list of selected items and you can set them as selected (checkStatus will be true).

Answer (score 0):

MVC does not have ViewState like ASP.Net WebForms (Not sure viewstate is a feature or drawback). So you have to save the state of the checkbox using a hidden field or a variable. You can try this with jquery and ajax